# How can I remove the space after "Sorted:[space]" when there are no input number?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code to sort a vector of integers. My code is completed, and it works. How can I remove the space after "Sorted:[space]" when there are no input number? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/* sort function */
void sort(vector<int>& v)
{
   for (int inc1 = 0; inc1 < v.size() - 1; ++inc1)
  {
    int minimum = inc1;

    for (int inc2 = inc1; inc2 < v.size(); ++inc2)
    {
        if (v[inc2] < v[minimum])
        {
            minimum = inc2;
        }
    }

    if (minimum != inc1)
    {
        int temporary = v[minimum];
        v[minimum] = v[inc1];
        v[inc1] = temporary;
    }

    if (v.empty())
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}

/* display function */
void display(vector<int> v)
{
  for (int inc1 = 0; inc1 < v.size(); ++inc1)
  {
    cout << v[inc1];
    if (inc1 != v.size() - 1)
    {
        cout << ", ";
    }
  }

cout << endl;
}

/* main function */

int main()
{
  /* getting inputs */
  cout << "Enter integers (one on each line, entering an empty line quits):" << endl;
vector<int> v;
string myString;

while (getline(cin, myString))
{
    /* if encounters a empty line, prints the output */
    if (myString.length() == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    /* if not add values to the vector */
    else
    {
        v.push_back(atoi(myString.c_str()));
    }
}

cout << "Sorted: ";

/* function call to sort */
sort(v);
/* function call to display */
display(v);
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @Steephen: But I need to keep the space when it has input numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line `cout << "Sorted: ";` with following

```
v.empty()? cout << "Sorted:": cout << "Sorted: ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no input number then your vector will be empty. So you could use a conditional based on that to print the extra space or not.

Comment: But I am not sure where should I put this condition statement.